# Closed source software with licensed open source libraries.

Tags: java, licensing, itext, jfreechart

I'm developing a Java application for the company I currently work at.
I want to keep secret the source code but I need to know how to integrate the external libraries involved in the application (don't know how to license it).

I'm using these libraries:

- Xerial SQLiteJDBC (Apache License version 2.0)
- iTextPDF (AGPL)
- JFreeChart(LGPL)

P.S. The application will be used only on one computer and isn't going to be distributed.
Thank you!

Comment: If you are not distributing it (*including* not serving it over a Web server), then you're fine. None of those licenses prohibit non-distributional use, but the AGPL does place requirements on you if you convey the work as a service over a network. Copyleft licenses usually say, "whenever you share this work with someone else, you must offer the source code", so if you're not sharing it, you're in no trouble at all. (Non-copyleft free/open licenses generally place no appreciable requirements at all, except to preserve copyright notices so all authors can be credited.)

Comment: It's a desktop application working with a local database (SQLite).

Answer (score 3):

Read the licenses and follow their terms.

The only one that's tricky is the AGPL. Assuming you're in the United States, you should probably get a legal opinion stating that your use of that library is simply ordinary use and therefore doesn't require any licensing. In the United States, if you lawfully acquire a work, you needn't acquire or comply with a license just to use that work in the ordinary, expected way. The AGPL is not an EULA.

For example, say you buy a book and it contains a license that says, "In exchange for the right to read this book, you must go surfing at least once a year. Failure to comply with this license revokes your right to read this book". You can simply refuse the license and you still have the right to read the book because United States copyright law doesn't give a copyright holder the exclusive right to use the work. So you don't need any rights that the license offers since you already have them.

See [17 USC 106](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106) which lists the exclusive rights copyright holders have under US law. IANAL, so you should get a lawyer to give you a written opinion that you can legally rely on.

Comment: Note that the IP of iText is owned by a Belgian company. Belgian Copyright laws are very different from American copyright laws. The advice is very good: when in doubt, get legal counsel.